# Is there any easy way to compare alphanumerics without using regex?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to compare strings that sometimes have a character `A-Z` in front, to see if it exists in a list.

So compare something like `225` or `225.` and see if it exists in a list of values like this

```
225.0
235.9
A23.8
B56.0
345.8
```

My regex fails on `225.` (with the period). It should match the first one in the list, since they are the same numeric value.

```
if (codesList[i].IndexOf(".") < 0)
{
    code = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\\b" + codesList[i].Replace(".", "[.]") + "(?![.])\\b");
}
else
{
    code = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\\b" + codesList[i].Replace(".", "[.]") + "\\b");
}

if (code.IsMatch(stringToFind))
{
    found = true;
}
```

So then I though of using exact numeric value by converting to decimal.  But that doesn't work if the value is preceded by a character.

EDIT ->  I'm not sure how much more I can clarify other than I want to see if a string matches with an alphanumeric value in the list.  But it has to match in terms of numeric value (ignoring the alpha character for the moment) and once that matches the alpha character must match exactly.

So A57.0 should be a match with A57. and A57
But A57.01 will not match with A57. or A57 nor will Z57.

Same with regular numeric values
234.0 must equal 234 and 234.

Comment: We can't fix your regex if you don't describe exactly what it should match. From your list of examples it's unclear (to me at least) which ones are valid or not.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes You're not alone :)

Comment: Why can't you do `codesList[i].Contains("225")` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj May be to bug us? Just kidding ;) Op will be more than satisfied if you can fix his regex(If you understand the question).

Comment: With your edit it's still unclear to me *why* it would match the first one. I have a feeling you don't understand regexps completely, causing the miscommunication?

Comment: @Habib won't this fail?  "225".Contains("225.0")

Comment: @erotavlas it should be backwards "225.0".contains("225.")

Comment: @Smog no it is possible that I might end up the other way around in which Contains function will fail.

Comment: @erotavlas I've read your question thrice but can't figure what you want to do exactly... may be my comprehension has become poor. Can you please explain what you're after?

Comment: @erotavlas Would you be trying to match "23.8"? What about "B56.0"?

Comment: @AmitJoki I don't understand what is so difficult.  I want to see if an alphanumeric value is in a list of alphanumeric values. I will clarify a bit my OP.

Comment: @erotavlas Give us a series of value pairs and whether or not they should pass. Ie: Source / Value [PASS]. So it might be:
"255" | "255." [PASS]
"255." | "255" [FAIL]

Comment: so what you are saying is - only match where the fraction is 0 like - A24.4 will not match "A24" and "A24.".....so why the dot in your search? stringToFind should just be "A24" and would match if in the list exits an item with A24.0 only right?

Answer (score 1):

First you should remove all non numeric characters from the string that you try to compare.

Then convert to a number and compare.

```
    bool found = false;

    foreach(var code in codesList)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[^0-9\-\.]");
        code = rgx.Replace(code, "");

        double num;

        if(double.TryParse(code, num))
        {
            // floating point number comparison should be done against a delta,
            // adjust as needed
            if(Math.Abs(num - numberToFind) < 0.000001d)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Why use double instead of decimal here?

Comment: Removing non numeric characters may give the wrong result.

Comment: @ChuckBuford can you be more specific?

Comment: You would have to assume that the non-numeric characters could only appear at the beginning or the end, never in the middle.   Reviewing the question, that may be the case.

Answer (score 0):

This Should help you,but i still dont understand why you need the "." in the search string:

```
List<string> codelist = new List<string>()
{
     "225.01",
     "225.00",
     "235.9",
     "A23.8",
     "B56.0",
     "345.8",
     "ZR5.0"
};

string stringToFind = "225.";
bool found = false;

foreach (string item in codelist)
{
     string[] parts = item.Split('.');
     //Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]),if its 01 it will be false
     //because the int returned will be 1 so only fractions
     //with only 0 will be true
     if (Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]) == 0)
     {
         //will be true for the item "225.00" or "225.0"
         if ((found = stringToFind.Contains(parts[0])) == true)
            break;
     }
}
```

We do `stringToFind.Contains(parts[0]))` because thats the "changing" string it can have a dot or not and parts[0] will always have just the number in this example 225.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Match(string s1, string s2) {
    string alphas = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSVWXYZ";
    foreach (char chr in alphas) {
        s1 = s1.Replace(chr.ToString(), "");
        s2 = s2.Replace(chr.ToString(), "");
    }

    decimal d1 = decimal.Parse(s1);
    decimal d2 = decimal.Parse(s2);
    return d1 == d2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You said it should 'match the first item' in the list, but your code example just marks it as true. This is what you could do if you want specifically to know which item is the match:

```
var theCodeThatMatches = codesList.First(code => code.Contains("255"));

if(theCodeThatMatches == null) return;

//do stuff to theCodeThatMatches
```

Comment: I think OPs problem is that an exact match cant be done "255" != "255.0"

Answer (score -1):

if these items are in a List:

```
 string codeValue = "255";

 var results = listItems.Where(w => w.Value.IndexOf(codeValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: what does the `ToLower()` do?

Comment: Since these are string values, ToLower() prevents case from being an issue when he's doing the search.

Comment: Have you ever heard of case insensitive comparison ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I added that as an option in my response, but I think the ToLower is clearer on what the code is doing.

Comment: It may be clearer but it brings baggage to the application can that be avoided, like the [Turkish i Problem](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/).

Comment: Consider me educated. I updated my response accordingly.